# Unicode and Javascript: Invalid byte sequences

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

Some byte sequences are apparently invalid in Unicode encodings, and I know that some languages (Python for one) throw an error when that happens.

My question is: what happens in Javascript when receiving such a sequence during an `XMLHttpRequest` or `XDomainRequest`? Does the resulting string:

1. Get truncated when that happens?
2. Skip the bad sequence and start at the next byte(s)?
3. Continue decoding and only show the replacement � character when displayed?

If 3, then does the `charCodeAt` function return a valid character code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 3 happens.  It shows the � when displayed, and charCodeAt returns 0xFFFD, the � unicode character.

Comment: OK, thanks, that was what I was looking for. For the record, I just confirmed it using [this page](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt) and iterating through the `charCodeAt` values.

Comment: A great testing resource: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt